# Cockroach DB is slower in 64GB RAM cluster as compared to 32GB RAM cluster

Tags: github, cockroachdb

I have installed CockroachDB in below clusters
a. 3 nodes cluster in which every node has 32GB RAM
b. 3 nodes cluster in which every node has 64GB RAM

I am testing the performance by running the same queries(Select, join, insert, delete, aggregate functions, nested queries, concurrent queries) in both the clusters.

After testing for 3 times, I have found that 64GB cluster is slower than 32 GB cluster.
I was expecting 64GB RAM cluster would be faster than 32GB RAM cluster.

I am not able to find the suitable answers for the same.
Any answers or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the post! Without knowing the exact machine specs, configuration settings, and workload it would be hard to figure out what could be happening here :)

We have a Slack channel that might be a bit easier for back and forth on performance optimization, or a support ticket could be opened with a best effort SLA. If you have any more information on the run configuration that would be great too!

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/join-community/
https://support.cockroachlabs.com/hc/en-us

Comment: I found out the answer. https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/recommended-production-settings.html

Comment: @Shweta Can you please share your findings more specificly? Thanks in advance.